# Quem eram os rutenos?

Tags: história

Do **Canto III** de **[Os Lusíadas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Os_Lus%C3%ADadas)**:

> Agora nestas partes se nomeia 
> A Lápia fria, a inculta Noruega, 
> Escandinávia Ilha, que se arreia 
> Das vitórias que Itália não lhe nega. 
> Aqui, enquanto as águas não refreia 
> O congelado Inverno, se navega 
> Um braço do Sarmático Oceano 
> Pelo Brúsio, Suécio e frio Dano. 
>  
> Entre este Mar e o Tánais vive estranha  
> Gente, Rutenos, Moscos e Livónios,  
> Sármatas outro tempo; e na montanha  
> Hircínia os Marcomanos são Polónios.  
> Sujeitos ao Império de Alemanha 
> São Saxones, Boémios e Panónios 
> E outras várias nações, que o Reno frio 
> Lava, e o Danúbio, Amásis e Álbis rio.

---

Assumo que:

- Brúsio      = prussiano
- Dano        = dinamarquês
- Moscos      = moscovitas
- Suécio      = sueco
- [Tánais](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%A1nais) = [Dom](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rio_Dom) (que desagua no [Azov](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mar_de_Azove))

Em Portugal do século XVI, que povo (ou povos) era (ou eram) conhecido por *rutenos*? A [Ruténia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rut%C3%AAnia) é a latinização da [Rússia Medieval](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rus) (Русь). Hoje em dia, *ruteno* normalmente refere-se aos [rutenos dos Cárpatos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russinos). No entanto, em meados do século XVI, para os lusos da era, quem eram os rutenos? Curiosamente, para o Camões, os moscovitas não eram rutenos.

Comment: Eu não sei qual é a resposta mas como contributo deixo aqui um link para o artigo da wikipedia sobre a palavra Rutenos https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutenos